# JOLT transformation for JSON originally from Protobuf format

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, jolt

I have json converted from protobuf protocol with following format:

```
{
  "id": "6aa0734f-6d6a-4b95-8a2b-2dde346f9df7",
  "measurements": [
    {
      "ts": "1590331111510000000",
      "values": [
        {},
        {
          "name": 1,
          "value": -1.8093990087509155
        },
        {
          "name": 2,
          "value": 0.35456427931785583
        }
      ],
      "parameters": [
        "Stat",
        "VoltageAnglePhaseB"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

expected output is:

```
    {
      "id" : "6aa0734f-6d6a-4b95-8a2b-2dde346f9df7",
      "ts" : "1590331111510000000",
      "Stat":-1.8093990087509155,
      "VoltageAnglePhaseB":0.35456427931785583
    }
```

I've started my Jolt spec like this:

```
    [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "measurements": {
        "*": {
          "ts": "ts",
          "parameters": {
            "*": ""
          },
          "*": ""
        }
      }
    }
    }


    ]
```

But facing the problem to extract name and value from the JSON.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with 2 shift operations. First, shift the values to the valuesArr, same way shift the parameters to the parametersArr. Then match the values with the index.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "measurements": {
        "*": {
          "ts": "ts",
          "values": {
            "*": {
              "value": "valuesArr"
            }
          },
          "parameters": "parametersArr"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "ts": "ts",
      "valuesArr": {
        "*": "@(2,parametersArr[&])"
      }
    }
  }
]
```